# jpa, hibernate version to support createNativeQuery method

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ojdbc

I use the below jars:

```
hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.5.3-Final
hibernate-core:jar:3.5.3-Final
org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final
com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.1.0
```

When I am trying execute `createNativeQuery` I am facing the exception:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT B_ID, B_LAN FROM BOOK");
List<Object[]> books = q.getResultList();
```

**Exception :**

```
select
       B_ID,
       B_LAN
 from
       BOOK

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:91) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1034) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:194) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:791) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:866) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1186) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3387) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3431) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.pmiExecuteQuery(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:1112) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:714) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1849) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:718) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2294) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:3.5.3-Final]
```

**Question:**

Is this because of the jar version which I am using is not supporting `createNativeQuery` method?

Which version of hibernate-jpa jar does support `createNativeQuery`?

Comment: is Book the name of the table or jpa entity?

Comment: BOOK is the table name

Comment: try to turn on hibernate debug logging. Does it produce a query just before the exception is thrown?

Comment: Yes. It produces the query and then the exception is thrown

Comment: can you add that produced sql?

Comment: Yes. I added in the post (In exception block)

Comment: Also post your `Book` entity.

Comment: Do the normal jpa queries work? Is there only problem with native queries? If so does problem occur in any native query or only this one?

Comment: yes other jpa queries run perfectly.

Comment: Thanks all for support. I found the issue. This is the query which points to new table and new schema and I was pointing to another schema on which other jpa queries are written.